# pytest assertion results in false but does not give more information about failure

Tags: python, pytest, assert

I am new to pytest and below is my code. I am using assertions. The assertion is working correct which is false as the data does not match. I need help in capturing what data is not matching.

```
def test_content_database():
    records_src = [(1,James,smith,123),(2,Granpa,smith,124),(3,Linda,smith,123)]
    records_trg = [(1,James,smith,**124**),(2,Granpa,**ron**,124),(3,Linda,smith,123)]
    print("ASSERTION RESULTED IN : ", all([a == b for a, b in zip(records_src, records_trg)]))
    assert all([a == b for a, b in zip(records_src, records_trg)]), "DATA IS NOT MATCHING"
```

**Console output is false which is correct but I would like to capture what data is not matching **

```
main_test.py:8 (test_content_database)
def test_content_database():
        records_src = dbcon.get_data_connection_src()
        records_trg = dbcon.get_data_connection_trg_diff()
        print("ASSERTION RESULTED IN : ", all([a == b for a, b in zip(records_src, records_trg)]))
>       assert all([a == b for a, b in zip(records_src, records_trg)]), "DATA IS NOT MATCHING"
E    AssertionError: DATA IS NOT MATCHING
E    assert False
E     +  where False = all([False, False, True, True, True, True, ...])

main_test.py:13: AssertionError
```

Comment: You can't. `all` itself does not return any more information than `True` or `False`. If you want to know exactly which elements are `False` you will have to manually iterate over the list

Comment: I would recommend not packing so much into a single line assertion -- you'd be best to have an actual loop with an individual assertion in it (and pytest will show you the differences then)

Answer (score 0):

How about `assert records_src == records_trg` because you are anyways checking equality?

On a side note, you can add a pytest cli option - `--show-locals`